# Declare Type of Class that Wraps an Object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a Javascript Class that Wraps an Object and provides additional properties.
Now, I want to create type declarations for this class, and I want to encode this "wrapping functionality" in the type declarations.

To explain, here is a simplified example class:

```js
// apiObj.js
class ApiObj {
    constructor(obj) {
        for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(obj)) {
            this[key] = val
        }
    }

    get myAdditionalFeature() {
       return "this is an example"
    }
}
```

That is, we can use `ApiObj` like so:

```js
const myObj = { a: "test" }
const apiWrapper = new ApiObj(myObj)
const valA = apiWrapper.a // "test"
const valAdditionalFeature = apiWrapper.myAdditionalFeature // "this is an example"
```

on "apiWrapper", both `a` and `myAdditionalFeature` are available.

How can I use Typescript to declare a class `ApiObj`, that wraps a given type `T` (so it has all keys with values of `T`) and some additional values?

Here's things I tried

1. Make `ApiObj` extend `T`:

```js
// apiObj.d.ts

declare class ApiObj<T> extends T {
// doesn't work, does not recognize the property "a" then,
// only the additional properties introduced by ApiObj
    constructor(obj: T)
    get myAdditionalFeature: string
}
```

2. Use a type intersection alias:

```js
// apiObj.d.ts
declare class ApiObj<T> {
    constructor(obj: T)
    get myAdditionalFeature: string
}

type ApiObj<T> = ApiObj<T> & T // type intersection -> this seems to create the correct type
```

However, when I use this type, I can not access the original objects properties:

```js
// usage.ts
interface Test {
    a: string
}
const myTest: Test = {
    a: "Test"
}

const myApi = new ApiObj(myTest)

const myVal = myApi.a // Error: property a does not exist on type
// ApiObj<Test>
```

Is the described behaviour possible with Typescript? If so, what is the correct way to achieve it?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:** I found a workaround, which is to create an external factory function, that uses the type alias. The class declaration is prefixed, so that the type alias shadows the class declaration.

```js
// apiObj.d.ts
declare class $ApiObj {
    get myAdditionalFeature: string
}

type ApiObj<T> = $ApiObj & T

declare function apiObj<T extends Object>(obj: T): ApiObj<T>
```

And used like so:

```js
// usage.ts
interface Test {
    a: string
}
const myTest: Test = {
    a: "Test"
}

const t = apiObj(myTest)
t.a // works
t.myAdditionalFeature // works
```

However, the original Problem remains, I can not achieve this typing for the constructor of ApiObj, so I can only instantiate objects using this factory function.

Comment: How did you use the generic type? Did you leave it to be inferred? If so, what was the parameter `T` inferred as?

Comment: @Bergi I tried both now, it says "property a does not exist", and the type inferred / declared by me is ApiObj<Test>, using the code I posted above, in my edited version of the question.